# Telethon, global variable stops websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, telethon, quart, hypercorn

So, I am trying to use telethon,quart and websockets to create a dynamic page that only receives updates when the client receives a message event:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection, events, utils
import hypercorn.asyncio
from quart import Quart, websocket

from variables import api_id, api_hash

from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

# Session name, API ID and hash to use; loaded from environmental variables
SESSION = 'quart';

# Telethon client
client = TelegramClient(SESSION, api_id, api_hash)
client.parse_mode = 'html'  


###paginas html
teste_html = """
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quart + Telethon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Página de teste!</h1>
    <p>No momento, estamos testando o websocket</p>
    <ul></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/random');

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var messages_dom = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        var message_dom = document.createElement('li');
        var cotent_dom = document.createTextNode('Received: ' + event.data);
        message_dom.appendChild(cotent_dom);
        messages_dom.appendChild(message_dom);
    };
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
"""

###

app = Quart(__name__)
lock = asyncio.Lock();


@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    await client.connect()


@app.after_serving
async def cleanup():
    await client.disconnect()

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def receber(event):
    global x;
    try:
        sender = await event.get_sender();
        name = utils.get_display_name(sender);
        message = name + "::::::" + event.text + "\n";
        await lock.acquire();
        x = message;
        try:
            file = open('msg.txt', '+a');
            file.write(message);
            file.close();

        finally:
            lock.release()

    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print("Adeus!");

    except Exception as e:
        print("\n======ERRO======\n");
        print(e);


###websockets
@app.websocket('/random')
async def random():
    global x;
    import random
    from time import sleep

    try:
        while True:
            if x != 1:
                print(x);
                data = random.randint(0,5);
                data = str(data);
                await websocket.send(f"Quart enviou 1: {data}");
            else:
                besteira = 0;

            sleep(1);
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e);
        print("erro 2");


@app.route('/')
async def hello_world():
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello World')
    #return 'Message Sent!'
    return teste_html;

async def main():
    await hypercorn.asyncio.serve(app, hypercorn.Config())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 1;
    try:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Adeus!");

    except Exception as e:
        print(e);
```

The idea is that, when a first new message is received, the websocket will start to send random numbers to the page (I am begginer), however, it just, locks, it not even writes on the msg.txt file, and here is the thin, **this only happens if you use the *if* statement**. If you take away the if statement, it runs, slow, but it runs, but if you put the if statement, it just locks.

If you can't help me, can you suggest me any quart/telethon/websocket tutorial? Or an example? If not,the is any other way to do this? Any better way to create a dynamic page?

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I am idiot, I was using **synchronous** sleep, I don't know exactly how this was breaking stuff, but it was, here is the fixed API:

```py
@app.websocket('/random')
async def random():
    global mensagem;
    import random
    #from time import sleep
    mensagem_antiga = "";
    
    try:
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            
            if mensagem_antiga != mensagem:
                await websocket.send(f" {mensagem}");
                mensagem_antiga = mensagem;

            await asyncio.sleep(1);
            
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e);
        print("erro 2");
```

Comment: Synchronous sleep puts the entire thread to sleep, so the `asyncio` event loop cannot run (and therefore, all `async` things "stop").

Comment: Yeah, after 2 days on this I realized that, thanks anyway!

Comment: PS: @Lonami I just wanted to say that I am loving to use Telethon, it's simply amazing what you managed to create! Keep the great work!